# creating the proper component in reactnative

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create my own component in React Native and call it in the render of the app class however the error is shown:

> typeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'instance.render ()')

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';

class MeuComponente extends Component {
  return() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Primeiro Parametro</Text>
        <Text>Segundo Parametro</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <MeuComponente></MeuComponente>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote return() instead of render, try

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';

class MeuComponente extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Primeiro Parametro</Text>
        <Text>Segundo Parametro</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <MeuComponente></MeuComponente>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: No reason to apologize, we are here to help. Vamo Brasil